# Best way to run a SQL query for different dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application that records the sessions of various devices connected to a server. The database has a table `session`, with the columns `device_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`. To know the number of devices connected on a given date, I can use the request :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_id)
FROM session
WHERE :date >= start_date AND (:date <= end_date OR end_date IS NULL)
```

where `:date` is passed as a parameter to the prepared statement.

This works fine, but if I want to know the number of devices for every days of the year, that makes 365 queries to run, and I'm afraid things could get very slow. It doesn't feel right to be iterating on the date in PHP, it seems to me that there should be a more optimal way to do this, with a single query to the database.

1. Is it possible do this with a single query?
2. Would it actually be faster than to iterate on the date in PHP an running multiple queries?

---

EDIT to answer the comments :

- I do want the number for each separate day (to draw a graph for example), not just the sum
- the datatype is DATE

Comment: have you tried just setting start date to 2021-01-01 and end date to 2021-12-31 (for example)? That'll get you all the sessions within the year. You've given yourself a self-imposed limitation by using a single value `:date` twice for two different parameters in your SQL, meaning that you can never look at more than one date.

Comment: You might need to tweak the query slightly of course, so that it checks whether start_date is greater than the first date parameter and also less than the second one. Or, do you need to see if a session _overlaps_ the date range? e.g. if the start date is before the first date, but the end date is after it, would you want that included in the results?

Comment: You want the results for each day in that range? And what is the datatype of start and end dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you first need a table of dates, something like:

```sql
create table dates(dt date);
insert into dates(dt) values
('2001-01-01'),
('2001-01-02'),
...
('2100-12-31')
```

And use a query like so:

```sql
select dates.dt, count(session.device_id)
from dates
join session on start_date <= dates.dt and (dates.dt <= end_date or end_date is null)
-- change to left join to include zero counts
where dates.dt >= :date1 and dates.dt <= :date2
group by dates.dt
```

PS: since you mentioned charts I might add that it is possible to avoid the table of dates. However, the result will only contain dates on which the count of devices changed. Chart APIs usually accept this kind of data but still create data points for all dates in between.

Comment: This worked, thank you, I wouldn't have thought of adding another table. I will have to remember to update it before 2100 tho !

Comment: If a device can show up twice on a single `dt`, then you may need `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT()`.